# Jquery Drag Drop not working correctly in a Dynamics CRM Web Resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I have made a drag drop functionality using JQuery, it is working well when applied on static records, as I am using ajax call and updating the div with several records, but Drag functionality is not working on dynamically created records.

at first I am populating my div with records, and after this I am running my code to make divs draggable,

after trying lot, I put an alert after the below code. and drag drop works fine, but when I remove only the alert statement, again it does not work.

what may be the reason?

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".dragable").draggable({
cancel: "a.ui-icon",
revert: true,
helper: "clone",
cursor: "move",
live: true,
revertDuration: 0
});
});
alert("Drag code executed.");
```

Comment: Can you add a link to an example page, maybe on jsfiddle?

Comment: as it is running on an online CRM instance, how can I show you, ajax is loading records from Dynamics CRM...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get `delegated Handler` for `draggable` *JQuery-UI* . But I think it cannot be done  so what you can do is *destroy* the `draggable` property and assign again once the dynamic contents are added.

```
$('.draggable').draggable('destroy');
$('.draggable').draggable();
```